# How to load a SWF compiled by Flex into a SWF compiled by Flash CS4

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flash-cs4, flash-builder

I compiled a simple AS3 project using Flex 3.5 (also tried Flex 4.1) to create a small swf which draws a simple red square on screen. Nothing too complex that requires special flashplayer support (see code below)

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    /**
     * @author John Lindquist
     */
    [SWF(width="1024", height="768", frameRate="24")]
    public class EasingATimeline extends Sprite 
    {
        private var square:Sprite;
        private static const STEP_DURATION:Number = 1;

        public function EasingATimeline()
        {
            square = new Sprite();  
            square.graphics.beginFill(0xcc0000);
            square.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
            square.graphics.endFill();

            square.x = 100;
            square.y = 50;

            addChild(square);
        }
    }
}
```

and tried to load it into a AS2  swf I have compiled using Flash CS4. But that just didn't work. I don't get any errors when loading and the AS2 swf can load any swf, either compiled in AS2 or AS3 by Flash.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Flex/Flash builder is only for as3. So you can't load it into an as2 swf. You can however create a new as3 file in flash and load both your as2 swf and your flex swf and position them accordingly. Loading swfs is easy in as3:

```
var as2:Loader = new Loader();
as2.load(new URLRequest("myAS2Thing.swf"));
as2.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onDoneLoadingAS2);
function onDoneLoadingAS2(e:Event):void{
 as2.x = 100;
 as2.y = 100;
  addChild(as2);
}
```

Comment: I would have expected that as long as the player supports it (AKA FP9 or higher) that you should be able to load any SWF.  I've never tried it, though.  Check out this http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/141/tn_14190.html for info on how to load external SWFs using both AS2 and AS3.  How would the AS2 SWF know how the SWF it is loading uses AS3?  And why would it matter?